# fatal: could not read password for 'https://[PAT]@tfs.**.com' no such device or address

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, devops, tekton-pipelines, openshift-pipelines

I'm building a Tekton task on Openshift pipelines and trying to clone the source code from my GIT repository.
I'm cloning the repo in my script using the below

```
git clone 'https://[PAT]@tfs.**.com/[org]/[project]/_git/[repo]'
```

but always getting the error below

```
fatal: could not read password for 'https://[PAT]@tfs.**.com' no such device or address
```

I created a secret with the username and password(PAT) and added the secret to pipeline service account but still getting the same error.
I searched a lot about the issue and nothing from all the solutions I found worked with me.

Comment: As far as I know, the Tekton task on Openshift pipelines a cloud-native, continuous integration and continuous delivery (CI/CD) solution based on Kubernetes resources.  This is a cloud service. And TFS is hosted on local machine. In this case the Tekton task is not able to access the TFS directly due to the local firewall. You may need to check the IPs/domains of the Tekton task and add it to the local firewall of tfs. Or you can consider using Azure DevOps Service to host the repo and have a try.

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT 
There's no firewall between the machines hosting OCP and TFS machine.
My Openshift cluster is a private cluster and installed on a local machines in the same subnet of TFS machine and no firewalls between them.

Comment: Can you share the current Pipeline sample of the YAML File?